# Dealing with Aces in Blackjack?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, methods, while-loop

I'm trying to edit my "score" function so that if and when an Ace is dealt, the for-loop checks to see if it is an Ace and if the sum is greater than 21, and then subtracts 10 if that is the case. The variable "aces" keeps track of the number of aces. I was given this "hint" to use a While-Loop:

"At the end you could check whether the sum of the scores was over 21 and the number of aces was non-zero. while this is true, you could decrease the sum by 10 and decrease your aces count by 1, "using up" your aces by converting them from an 11 to 1 (reducing the total score by 10). You could then keep doing this process until you either ran out of aces or your score goes under 21."

I'm not quite sure how to fix this. Can someone help me out please? Thanks.

```
function Hand(){
    var handArray =[];
    handArray[0]=deal();
    handArray[1]=deal();
    this.getHand = function(){
        return handArray;  
    };  
    this.score = function(){
        var sum = 0;
        var aces = 0;
        for(var i =0; i < handArray.length; i++){
            sum += handArray[i].getValue();

            while(handArray[i].getValue()===11 && sum >21){
                aces += 1; 
                sum -= 10; 
            };
         }; 
        return sum;
    };
    this.hitMe = function(){
        var newCard = deal();
        handArray.push(newCard);
    };
 };
```

Comment: This screams of a "Do my homework for me" question. What isn't working? What have you tried? What specific programming problem are you trying to solve (The technical problem, not the real life situation it relates to)?

Comment: It's actually just a Codecademy thing. When I submit the code the feedback I get from Codecademy says:  "Make sure your score method can handle aces with more than two cards"

Comment: Fair enough, but you're still asking for help without really specifying the technical issue you're trying to solve. You're just giving the whole brief, you need to identify a specific problem.

Comment: We're here to help, but this isn't a programming issue, this is a logic issue. You'd do well to answer it yourself because this sort of mental workout is at the very least a weekly, if not daily, problem in development.

Comment: The biggest hint I can provide is that any two aces with scores of 11 will be a losing hand.

Comment: @KnowledgeMC: If you were to perform the suggested logic with pen-and-paper, what doesn't make sense?  How have you attempted to translate that logic to code?

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone. I'll try to look over the code again and see what's going wrong with the logic.

Comment: Can I make a minor suggestion?  For the sake of consistency, rename `score` to `getScore`.  This keeps it consistent with the `getHand` function, and makes its intent and purpose clearer.